# Why does some SSL clients need to download a server SSL certificate and store it

Tags: ssl

I'm building a PHP web app that uses AWS RDS. In order to make the connection encrypted, I need to download the SSL certificate from RDS and store it on the app server so that the app can use it. But I remember when I use SQL workbench it somehow knows how to connect with SSL to the RDS instance without me downloading the certificate and telling it where the certificate is stored. Also after reviewing the way how HTTPS works, I know that the client doesn't need to store a certificate the first time it connects to a server, it download the certificate itself. So my question is for my app to connect to RNS instance using SSL, why do I need to first download the cert and tell my app where it's stored? Shouldn't my app know how to get the certificate itself?

Answer (score 0):

Certificate validation requires a trusted root CA. Trusted means that the CA is in the local trust store. Depending on what site you connect to and what certificate you get it might be a certificate issued by a CA you already trust or not. In the latter case you would need to explicitly get the so far untrusted CA certificate first and somehow treat it as trusted.

The need to explicitly import a CA as trusted is typically true for self-signed certificates which is usually considered bad practice but depending on the specific environment might make sense. It can also happen for company specific CA but these should better by rolled out to the various systems by an automated process. It might also happen when a misconfigured server does not send a required intermediate certificate, in which case it would be better to fix this server.

Note that you should not import arbitrary CA certificates and consider these trusted. Whoever owns this CA can issue arbitrary certificates even for existing domains like google.com and your application will then blindly trust these faked certificates too, making man in the middle attacks possible.